# How can i track Multiple Tracking Obkject in Google Universal Analytics Code

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I wan't to track my website and give them two Accounts

My code:

```
    <script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-1234-5', 'auto',{'name': 'partnerTracker'});
  ga('partnerTracker.require', 'displayfeatures');
  ga('partnerTracker.send', 'pageview');

  ga('create', 'UA-678-9', 'auto',{'name': 'secondTracker'});
  ga('secondTracker.require', 'displayfeatures');
  ga('secondTracker.send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Does anybody know if that works ? I cound not find a good tutorial to find that out.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to uniquely name one tracker at the least:

```
ga('create', 'UA-1234-5', 'auto');
ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
ga('send', 'pageview');

ga('create', 'UA-678-9', 'auto',{'name': 'secondTracker'});
ga('secondTracker.require', 'displayfeatures');
ga('secondTracker.send', 'pageview');
```

Comment: how can i do that if i have 3 objects

Comment: Then you just add a third tracker named differently from the first two.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works.

I don't know of a tutorial on this, but here's the official documentation about using multiple trackers:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#multipletrackers

And if you want to test it to make sure it works, you can use `analytics_debug.js` to see exactly what's happening in the developer console. Here's some info on debugging:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#debug